# How to automatically update id and created_at columns for a model that wasn't originally an Active Record model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to start persisting data that was (intentionally) not being persisted before.

The model originally looked like this:

```
class Inquiry
  include ActiveAttr::Model
  include ActiveAttr::MassAssignment

  attribute :name
  attribute :email
  attribute :phone
  attribute :company
  attribute :content

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :company, :content

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :format => {:with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i } 
  validates :phone, allow_blank: true, :format => {:with => /^\+?([\d]{10,13})?$/}
  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

I ran a migration to create an inquiries table and changed the model file to look like this:

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :phone, :company, :content

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :format => {:with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i } 
  validates :phone, allow_blank: true, :format => {:with => /^\+?([\d]{10,13})?$/}
  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

I realized my models didn't have a created_at or updated_at field so I ran a migration and placed 'change_table(:inquiries) { |t| t.timestamps }' in the change method.

Now when I run my specs I get the following error:

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, created_at, updated_at

I would like to remedy this problem by modifying what already exists rather than deleting the model, dropping the table, and Rails generating a new model. I know I can pass id, created_at, and updated_at into attr_accessible but I would like to preserve Active Record's default behavior of handling their assignment automatically and preventing mass assignment.

Comment: check your specs if it's setting those attributes via mass assignment when creating the records.

Comment: @jvnill The factories are not setting those attributes via mass assignment.

Comment: The error seems to be invoked in a controller action when I try to instantiate a new Inquiry via Inquiry.new. The model specs are passing without any issues.

Comment: check the passed params to the controller in the test.

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the problem. I was making a post request and passing the model attributes by calling .attributes on the factory model in the spec. .attributes appears to return all attributes including id, created_at, and updated_at.